# Vue 3 Router does not append a trailing slash to a parent view and so will not render the default child vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

My nested vue-router will not append the trailing slash to the parent link and so will not render the assigned component. If I manually enter the slash into the url and hit enter in the browser it will render.

The nested view uses 3 components:

1. CustomersView.vue
2. CustomersMainView.vue
3. CustomersDetailView.vue

The nested path structure looks like:

```
{
    path: '/app',
    component: Dashboard,
    children: [
        { path: 'dashboard', name: 'DashboardHome', component: DashboardHome, meta: {requiresAuth: true }},
        { path: 'my-profile', name: 'MyProfileView', component: MyProfileView, meta: {requiresAuth: true }},
        { path: 'contacts', name: 'ContactsView', component: ContactsView, meta: {requiresAuth: true }},
        {{
            path: 'customers',
            name: 'CustomersView',
            component: CustomersView,
            meta: {requiresAuth: true },
            children: [
                { path: '', name: 'CustomersMainView', component: CustomersMainView, meta: {requiresAuth: true } },
                { path: 'detail/:ID', name: 'CustomerDetailView', component: CustomerDetailView, meta: {requiresAuth: true } },
            ]
        },
}
```

I can see all of these views by manually entering the url.

```
myapp.com/customers/ <-- This renders the `CustomerMainView` properly
```

But when the link is rendered using the  in my sidebar navigation it does not append the trailing slash:

```
<!-- Customers -->
    <div class="nav-category-container">
        <div class="nav-category-item">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'CustomersView', params: {}}">Customers</router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It directs to

> myapp.com/customers

**It leaves off the trailing slash and so will not render the CustomerMainView component as directed in the router.**

How do I get that link to append the trailing slash? I thought it would do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding the slash in the child routes of your component?

```
 {
    path: 'customers',
    name: 'CustomersView',
    component: CustomersView,
    meta: {requiresAuth: true },
    children: [
        { path: 'customers', name: 'CustomersMainView', component: CustomersMainView, meta: {requiresAuth: true } },
        { path: 'detail/:ID', name: 'CustomerDetailView', component: CustomerDetailView, meta: {requiresAuth: true } },
    ]
},
```

Comment: i have put a slash at the end of customers which will append the slash but it will not load the component CustomersMainView. I tried adding 'customers' like you show but this only works for /customers/customers

Comment: I also added slashes to the child components front and back and every which way and that does not seem to work either.

Comment: If i make the path for the parent "/stm/customers/" then the slash is there on click but no render of the customerMainView component, BUT if i go to the url and remove the trailing slash it renders the component.. So, I have no clue whats going on LOL